# How to use a very long integer to compute a value in C++?

Tags: c++, modulo

I need to compute `(n*(2n+1)*(n+1)*(3(n^2)+3n+1))/30 modulo m` where:
- 30 & m can be non co-prime
- `n` can have values up to `10^10` (too big for `long long int`)
- `m` can have any value up to 10000

I have tried this:

```
long long int tp1;
double k;
k=n;
k=k*((2*n)+1);
k=k*(n+1);
k=k*((3*n*n)+(3*n)-1);
tp1=fmod(k/30,m);
```

Comment: Use a type able to hold all integers up to at least 10000^2 (That would be `long long` for example), and do early and eager modulo-reductions to keep the values acceptably low. (10^10)^5 is far more than 2^64. (I used ^ to mean power instead of the C-operator bitwise-XOR). (% is the integer remainder operator in C, read about the difference between remainder and modulo)

Comment: Aside (also @Fr): Do not try to do exact integer computations with floating-point, if you can avoid it. There's absolutely no need here.

Comment: Hint: `(x * y) mod m` == `((x mod m) * (y mod m)) mod m`.

Comment: @molbdnilo but how wud i handle `(x/y) % m`  i have tried  `(x % m / y^-1 ) % m` but still of no use

Comment: @molbdnilo but lets say my x was 10040 and m was 100 and y is 30 so  `10040 % 100 = 40` and `40 / 30 = 1` whereas `10040/30 = 335` and `335 % 100 = 35 `

Comment: @molbdnilo We haven't been told the value of `m`. If `m` is 2^89 your multiplicative identity does not help (the one for division is plain wrong).

Comment: @PascalCuoq The limit on `m` (10000) was removed in an edit so I put it back. I got a bit carried away on the division, I'm afraid. Unnecessarily, too.

Comment: Out of interest, what are you supposed to do if your polynomial in `n` doesn't turn out to be divisible by `30`? It's not clear that this question is well-defined in its current form.

Answer (score 3):

[As noted by molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767201/how-to-use-a-very-long-integer-to-compute-a-value-in-c#comment40295513_25767201), you can do all the calculations modulo a certain number.

To expand that idea:

- `(x * y) mod m` is the same as `((x mod m) * (y mod m)) mod m`
- `(x + y) mod m` is the same as `((x mod m) + (y mod m)) mod m`

However

- `(x / y) mod m` is not the same as `((x mod m) / (y mod m)) mod m`

Therefore, you have to calculate `n*(2n+1)*(n+1)*(3(n^2)+3n+1) mod (30 * m)`, and divide that by 30.

P.S. I assumed the division operation means the same as in c++, "divide with rounding down".

Comment: sir we have b & m non com-prime here so would i work for that?

Answer (score 1):

For very long integer, use GMP from the Gnu project.
[GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

With the c++ variant (gmpxx), you have just to déclare your number like this :

```
mpz_class number;
```

And you can effectuate your calculs like this :

```
number = k*((3*n*n)+(3*n)-1);
```

where k and n can be int or mpz_class (or many others).

I hope that will help you !